# GreenSocks Tweenmax animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I am new to Tweenmax animation and i am trying to animate an id selector and unfortunately nothing is happening. both selector and content do nothing. Some one help me out, here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my first tween</title> 

        <style>
            body {
                background-color:silver;
            }

            #sample {
                width: 402px;
                height: 60px;
                background-color:teal;
                padding: 8px;
            }
        </style>    

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.gsap.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.11.6/TweenMax.min.js">/script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="sample">
            <!-- Some content -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the js

```
var drew = document.getElementById("sample"); //or use jQuery's $("#sample")
TweenLite.to(sample, 1.5, {width:100});
```

Comment: ah i finally figured it out. i'd missed the jquery show handles $(function(){});

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        TweenLite.to($("#sample"), 1.5, {width:100});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  var drew = document.getElementById("sample"); //or use jQuery's $("#sample")
  TweenLite.to(drew , 1.5, {width:100});
```

you put sample instead of drew.